# Python performance: iteration and operations on nested lists

Tags: performance, python

**Problem**  Hey folks.  I'm looking for some advice on python performance.  Some background on my problem:

Given:

1. A `(x,y)` mesh of nodes each with a value `(0...255)` starting at 0
2. A list of `N` input coordinates each at a specified location within the range `(0...x, 0...y)`
3. A value `Z` that defines the "neighborhood" in count of nodes

Increment the value of the node at the input coordinate and the node's neighbors.   Neighbors beyond the mesh edge are ignored.  (No wrapping)

*BASE CASE:* A mesh of size `1024x1024` nodes, with `400` input coordinates and a range `Z` of `75` nodes.

Processing should be `O(x*y*Z*N)`.  I expect x, y and Z to remain roughly around the values in the base case, but the number of input coordinates N could increase up to 100,000.  **My goal** is to minimize processing time.

**Current results** Between my start and the comments below, we've got several implementations.

Running speed on my 2.26 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo with Python 2.6.1:

```
  f1: 2.819s
  f2: 1.567s
  f3: 1.593s
   f: 1.579s
 f3b: 1.526s
  f4: 0.978s
```

`f1` is the initial naive implementation:  three nested `for` loops.
`f2` is replaces the inner `for` loop with a list comprehension.
`f3` is based on Andrei's suggestion in the comments and replaces the outer `for` with `map()`
`f` is Chris's suggestion in the answers below
`f3b` is kriss's take on `f3`
`f4` is Alex's contribution.

Code is included below for your perusal.

**Question** How can I further reduce the processing time?  I'd prefer sub-1.0s for the test parameters.

**Please,** keep the recommendations to native Python.  I know I can move to a third-party package such as [numpy](https://numpy.org/), but I'm trying to avoid *any* third party packages.   Also, I've generated random input coordinates, and simplified the definition of the node value updates to keep our discussion simple.  The specifics have to change slightly and are outside the scope of my question.

thanks much!

---

**`f1` is the initial naive implementation:  three nested `for` loops.**

```
def f1(x,y,n,z):
    rows = [[0]*x for i in xrange(y)]

    for i in range(n):
        inputX, inputY = (int(x*random.random()), int(y*random.random()))
        topleft = (inputX - z, inputY - z)
        for i in xrange(max(0, topleft[0]), min(topleft[0]+(z*2), x)):
            for j in xrange(max(0, topleft[1]), min(topleft[1]+(z*2), y)):
                if rows[i][j] <= 255: rows[i][j] += 1
```

**`f2` is replaces the inner `for` loop with a list comprehension.**

```
def f2(x,y,n,z):
    rows = [[0]*x for i in xrange(y)]

    for i in range(n):
        inputX, inputY = (int(x*random.random()), int(y*random.random()))
        topleft = (inputX - z, inputY - z)
        for i in xrange(max(0, topleft[0]), min(topleft[0]+(z*2), x)):
            l = max(0, topleft[1])
            r = min(topleft[1]+(z*2), y)
            rows[i][l:r] = [j+(j<255) for j in rows[i][l:r]]
```

**UPDATE:** `f3` is based on [Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124831/andrei-tanasescu)'s suggestion in the comments and replaces the outer `for` with `map()`.  My first hack at this requires several out-of-local-scope lookups, specifically [recommended against](https://web.archive.org/web/20140210120732/http://www.python.org:80/doc/essays/list2str.html) by Guido: *local variable lookups are much faster than global or built-in variable lookups*   I hardcoded all but the reference to the main data structure itself to minimize that overhead.

```
rows = [[0]*x for i in xrange(y)]

def f3(x,y,n,z):
    inputs = [(int(x*random.random()), int(y*random.random())) for i in range(n)]
    rows = map(g, inputs)

def g(input):
    inputX, inputY = input
    topleft = (inputX - 75, inputY - 75)
    for i in xrange(max(0, topleft[0]), min(topleft[0]+(75*2), 1024)):
        l = max(0, topleft[1])
        r = min(topleft[1]+(75*2), 1024)
        rows[i][l:r] = [j+(j<255) for j in rows[i][l:r]]
```

**UPDATE3:** [ChristopeD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81179/christophed) also pointed out a couple improvements.

```
def f(x,y,n,z):
    rows = [[0] * y for i in xrange(x)]
    rn = random.random
    for i in xrange(n):
        topleft = (int(x*rn()) - z, int(y*rn()) - z)
        l = max(0, topleft[1])
        r = min(topleft[1]+(z*2), y)
        for u in xrange(max(0, topleft[0]), min(topleft[0]+(z*2), x)):
            rows[u][l:r] = [j+(j<255) for j in rows[u][l:r]]
```

**UPDATE4:** [kriss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168465/kriss) added a few improvements to `f3`, replacing min/max with the new ternary operator syntax.

```
def f3b(x,y,n,z):
    rn = random.random    
    rows = [g1(x, y, z) for x, y in [(int(x*rn()), int(y*rn())) for i in xrange(n)]]

def g1(x, y, z):
    l = y - z if y - z > 0 else 0
    r = y + z if y + z < 1024 else 1024
    for i in xrange(x - z if x - z > 0 else 0, x + z if x + z < 1024 else 1024 ):
        rows[i][l:r] = [j+(j<255) for j in rows[i][l:r]]
```

**UPDATE5:** [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) weighed in with his substantive revision, adding a separate `map()` operation to cap the values at 255 and removing all non-local-scope lookups.  The perf differences are non-trivial.

```
def f4(x,y,n,z):
    rows = [[0]*y for i in range(x)]
    rr = random.randrange
    inc = (1).__add__
    sat = (0xff).__and__
    
    for i in range(n):
        inputX, inputY = rr(x), rr(y)
        b = max(0, inputX - z)
        t = min(inputX + z, x)
        l = max(0, inputY - z)
        r = min(inputY + z, y)
        for i in range(b, t):
            rows[i][l:r] = map(inc, rows[i][l:r])
    for i in range(x):
      rows[i] = map(sat, rows[i])
```

Also, since we all seem to be hacking around with variations, here's my test harness to compare speeds: *(improved by ChristopheD)*

```
def timing(f,x,y,z,n):
    fn = "%s(%d,%d,%d,%d)" % (f.__name__, x, y, z, n)
    ctx = "from __main__ import %s" % f.__name__ 
    results = timeit.Timer(fn, ctx).timeit(10)
    return "%4.4s: %.3f" % (f.__name__, results / 10.0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print timing(f, 1024, 1024, 400, 75)
    #add more here.
```

Comment: I don't know if you've tried, but how about using map to replace the two outer for loops ? map is faster than for loops.

Comment: @Andrei -- I can't wrap my head around how I could replace the 'middle' for loop with a list comprehension/map -- main reason is I only wish to update a subset of both the lists at once.  (the [l:r] statement)  Post updated with a `map()` replacing the outer `for`

Comment: Also, try to always use `xrange` instead of `range`. In my experience, it's always faster. You may win a few ms

Comment: yep, use xrange for iterating. range for when you need a list containing points in the given range :D

Comment: in f4 you have `for item in rows[i][l:r]:` - that copies `rows[i][l:r]` and then changes each element in the copied list. It is inefficient and does not actually alter the original list.

Comment: @wallacoloo -- ha!  that's a good point.   I just tried `enumerate(),` but that was as bad as the original `f1` (2.8s).

Comment: @J.J. , @wallacoloo: updated my post below...

Comment: @ChristopheD -- updated with current versions.

Comment: @J.J.: your timings will get polluted by background noise. Use the timeit module. I'll add an example of its usage to my answer.

Comment: @Chris, that's why StackOverflow rocks; I learn all sorts of useful things.   Post updated.

Comment: There's a functional problem with the f2 above: What if for example half of the values in `rows[i][l:r]` are > 255: you'll be assigning the wrong slice... My answer got the same defect, updated it now...

Comment: Just a detail : is it voluntary you changed the initial <= 255 in f1 to a strict < 255 ? Is f1 the right one or the others ?

Comment: @kriss, I didn't intend to, but it's not that critical.  If it improves perf within that inner loop, I can account for the difference elsewhere in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my (slow-ish;-) first-day Macbook Air, 1.6GHz Core 2 Duo, system Python 2.5 on MacOSX 10.5, after saving your code in `op.py` I see the following timings:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import op' 'op.f1()'
10 loops, best of 3: 5.58 sec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import op' 'op.f2()'
10 loops, best of 3: 3.15 sec per loop
```

So, my machine is slower than yours by a factor of a bit more than 1.9.

The fastest code I have for this task is:

```
def f3(x=x,y=y,n=n,z=z):
    rows = [[0]*y for i in range(x)]
    rr = random.randrange
    inc = (1).__add__
    sat = (0xff).__and__

    for i in range(n):
        inputX, inputY = rr(x), rr(y)
        b = max(0, inputX - z)
        t = min(inputX + z, x)
        l = max(0, inputY - z)
        r = min(inputY + z, y)
        for i in range(b, t):
            rows[i][l:r] = map(inc, rows[i][l:r])
    for i in range(x):
      rows[i] = map(sat, rows[i])
```

which times as:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import op' 'op.f3()'
10 loops, best of 3: 3 sec per loop
```

so, a very modest speedup, projecting to more than 1.5 seconds on your machine - well above the 1.0 you're aiming for:-(.

With a simple C-coded extensions, `exte.c`...:

```
#include "Python.h"

static PyObject*
dopoint(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int x, y, z, px, py;
    int b, t, l, r;
    int i, j;
    PyObject* rows;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "iiiiiO",
                         &x, &y, &z, &px, &py, &rows
        ))
        return 0;

    b = px - z;
    if (b < 0) b = 0;
    t = px + z;
    if (t > x) t = x;
    l = py - z;
    if (l < 0) l = 0;
    r = py + z;
    if (r > y) r = y;

    for(i = b; i < t; ++i) {
        PyObject* row = PyList_GetItem(rows, i);
        for(j = l; j < r; ++j) {
            PyObject* pyitem = PyList_GetItem(row, j);
            long item = PyInt_AsLong(pyitem);
            if (item < 255) {
                PyObject* newitem = PyInt_FromLong(item + 1);
                PyList_SetItem(row, j, newitem);
            }
        }
    }

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef exteMethods[] = {
    {"dopoint", dopoint, METH_VARARGS, "process a point"},
    {0}
};

void
initexte()
{
    Py_InitModule("exte", exteMethods);
}
```

(note: I haven't checked it carefully -- I think it doesn't leak memory due to the correct interplay of reference stealing and borrowing, but it should be code inspected very carefully before being put in production;-), we could do

```
import exte
def f4(x=x,y=y,n=n,z=z):
    rows = [[0]*y for i in range(x)]
    rr = random.randrange

    for i in range(n):
        inputX, inputY = rr(x), rr(y)
        exte.dopoint(x, y, z, inputX, inputY, rows)
```

and the timing

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import op' 'op.f4()'
10 loops, best of 3: 345 msec per loop
```

shows an acceleration of 8-9 times, which should put you in the ballpark you desire. I've seen a comment saying you don't want any third-party extension, but, well, this tiny extension you could make entirely your own;-).  ((Not sure what licensing conditions apply to code on Stack Overflow, but I'll be glad to re-release this under the Apache 2 license or the like, if you need that;-)).

Comment: Alex, your python-only implementation clocks in at 0.979s on my machine.  Nicely done, sir.  The two `map()` operations, combined with moving *everything* to locals were the clever insights I couldn't see. // My concern with the c extension (and the various third-party libraries that will speed up the calculations) is the complications with the distribution.  I'm not certain the cross-platform/compilation concerns are worth the speedup in the long run.

Comment: @J.J, wow, 3+ times faster than my Macbook Air, you sure do have a neat machine. Yes, I split the two `map` calls so I wouldn't have to worry about "saturating to 255" multiple times, just once and for all in the second `map` (but do note it's _not_ perfect: it "wraps around" to the low 8 bits instead -- for your specific purpose you need a different `sat` which I suspect may not be quite as fast). I do understand the deployment problems with having to compile stuff...

Answer (score 2):

**1**. A (smaller) speedup could definitely be the initialization of your `rows`...

Replace

```
rows = []
for i in range(x):
    rows.append([0 for i in xrange(y)])
```

with

```
rows = [[0] * y for i in xrange(x)]
```

**2**. You can also avoid some lookups by moving `random.random` out of the loops (saves a little).

**3.** EDIT: after corrections -- you could arrive at something like this:

```
def f(x,y,n,z):
    rows = [[0] * y for i in xrange(x)]
    rn = random.random
    for i in xrange(n):
        topleft = (int(x*rn()) - z, int(y*rn()) - z)
        l = max(0, topleft[1])
        r = min(topleft[1]+(z*2), y)
        for u in xrange(max(0, topleft[0]), min(topleft[0]+(z*2), x)):
            rows[u][l:r] = [j+(j<255) for j in rows[u][l:r]]
```

EDIT: some new timings with timeit (10 runs) -- seems this provides only minor speedups:

```
import timeit
print timeit.Timer("f1(1024,1024,400,75)", "from __main__ import f1").timeit(10)
print timeit.Timer("f2(1024,1024,400,75)", "from __main__ import f2").timeit(10)
print timeit.Timer("f(1024,1024,400,75)", "from __main__ import f3").timeit(10)
```

```
f1 21.1669280529
f2 12.9376120567
f  11.1249599457
```

Comment: Chris, absolutely.  it was sloppy of me to ever do anything else.  updated, saved about 0.1s across the board.  post updated.

Comment: Ah, yessir.  Unnecessary slicing.  I'm a punk.  0.89s on my box with the test case parameters.

Comment: This `for item in rows[i][max(0, topleft[1]):min(topleft[1]+(z*2), y)]:` does not do what you want. It copies that area of the list, modifies some elements, but does nothing to the original `rows` list.

Comment: @wallacoloo: very true (obviously), I'll update my post in a minute.

Comment: `j+(0,1)[j<255]` can be simplified to `j+(j<255)`

Comment: @wallacoloo: good point thanks (it's a a tiny bit faster also)

Comment: They're both clever. I didn't know about the `j+(0,1)[j<255]` syntax -- and your simplification is almost *evil*.

Comment: It's code you won't often see in production code (you'll see it in code golf ;-) It's useful in this case though (to keep every value from the slice within the list comprehension (with the alternative if clause at the end you'll silently drop the values > 255 and end up with a shorter slice) and to increment the values at the same time.

Comment: As for point #1, this code is faster by 0.2 *milliseconds* on my computer: `tc = [0]*y; rows = [tc[:] for i in xrange(x-1)]; rows.append(tc)`. Yay micro-optimizations!

Answer (score 1):

in your f3 rewrite, g can be simplified. (Can also be applied to f4)

You have the following code inside a for loop.

```
l = max(0, topleft[1])
r = min(topleft[1]+(75*2), 1024)
```

However, it appears that those values never change inside the for loop. So calculate them once, outside the loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your f3 version I played with the code. As l and r are constants you can avoid to compute them in g1 loop. Also using new **ternary if** instead of min and max seems to be consistently faster. Also simplified expression with topleft. On my system it appears to be about 20% faster using with the code below.

```
def f3b(x,y,n,z):
    rows = [g1(x, y, z) for x, y in [(int(x*random.random()), int(y*random.random())) for i in range(n)]]

def g1(x, y, z):
    l = y - z if y - z > 0 else 0
    r = y + z if y + z < 1024 else 1024
    for i in xrange(x - z if x - z > 0 else 0, x + z if x + z < 1024 else 1024 ):
        rows[i][l:r] = [j+(j<255) for j in rows[i][l:r]]
```

Comment: kriss, well done!  my head is still stuck in python from 2002; I can't manage to think in terms of the new constructs available.   1.7s on my box with the test case parameters.

Comment: What if for example half of the values in `rows[i][l:r]` are > 255: you'll be assigning the wrong slice...

Comment: @ChristopheD: You are right. I just started working on f3 without checking the initial version. (O, my god, again a reminder of why I so love unit tests).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Python module in C, and control the performance as you want:
http://docs.python.org/extending/

Comment: Yep, but this has the same distribution challenges as third-party modules. I'd much prefer to stay all python.